# Как загружать комментарии для каждого поста WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Ситуация следующая
Есть сайт на WordPress, есть станица новости. Под ней кнопка загрузить еще, которая загружает через ajax новую новость. Все вроде отлично, только функция комментариев которая вызывается стандартной функции WP Выводится лишь для первого поста, а для тех что выводится через ajax - не выводится

Comment: Посмотрите куда по AJAX обращается плагин загрузки новостей. Там будет php обработчик, который делает запрос и берет новость. К нему добавьте функцию вывода комментариев (стандартную). Сейчас она там видимо отсутствует.

Comment: Что вы сделали для того, чтобы они выводились? Где код?